# Access file not opening.Error Messag you and another user are attempting to change the same data at same time

Tags: database, ms-access, jet

Access file not opening. Error Message:  The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at same time.

It is not repairing / compacting through database Jet Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive you are the only user in the database?  If it's on a network drive, try copying it to your local hard drive, doing the compact/repair there, and then copy it back to the network.  If it's on your local drive, try rebooting your computer, deleting the .LDB locking file in the same directory as your database (if it exists) and compact/repair again.

Comment: I m the only user and its on my local hard drive. compact/repair is not working same message appear. its not creating .ldb file, its not open from ms-access or through ado/odbc. when i m going to try open above message appear and same when repairing through odbc.

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question was posted half a year ago so this is too late to help the poster.

If there is no .ldb file, the database is copied locally (so no possibility of it being locked), you can't repair and JetComp (download from Microsoft) also won't repair then your database is corrupt and the only way forward is to restore from a backup. Sorry.